# Accessing json object in vb.net after converting from XML

Tags: json, xml, vb.net

I convert XML to JSON like so:

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(arg_strXml)
Dim jsonObject As String = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc)
```

Now I would like to be able to go into jsonObject to get values, like so

```
Dim mode As String = jsobObject.mode
```

Or more advanced example

```
Dim usersFirstName As String = jsonObject.people[1].firstname
```

Do I need to create a class which represents the XML structure or can I do it another way, even if I lose the intellisense, like so

```
Dim mode As String = jsonObject["mode"]
```

Comment: Its rather difficult to show you how to access the json data without seeing the json

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you first conversion was unnecessary,
you can access all values you need from xml with [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) and feature of `vb.net` [XML Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx)

```vb
Dim xmlString as String = "
<someobject>
    <property1>Value 1</property1>
    <property2>1001</property2>
</someobject>"

Dim xmlObject As XElement = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
Dim value1 As String = xmlObject.<property1>.First().Value
Dim value2 As String = xmlObject.<property2>.First().Value
```